# What is the upper limit of number of SNP based mutation in any protein?

Tags: mutations, gene, snp, protein-structure

I want to know if there is any upper limit of, how many point mutation a protein can have because of disease or nsSNPs? The general studies only focus mostly on a single or double site mutation of any protein structure.

Comment: Aren't you limiting yourself to "one" (**S**NP)? The more mutations, the more likely the protein will not be functional. Theoretically, there is no upper limit. The more vital the protein, the more likely a SNP will adversely affect the individual, and the more likely more mutations will be lethal.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: Actually, I wanted to know same thing. If there is any method to determine, how many mutation makes it lethal (or in other words non existent).

Comment: Which protein are you wondering about?

Comment: Depends on the protein. Also depends on the kind of substitution that is happening. Some functional proteins can tolerate deletion of huge segments. Selection would happen only if the SNP has an adverse effect under the ambient conditions.